how can i copy the files to corresponding folders
i have over 30k+ pdf files in a folder and most of them in fact useless, so i want to filter which i want to use so i created folders named with those i need and then i am trying to copy .pdf and .stp files in to corresponding folders, example:
i have file named XLM.371002.AA-A.pdf and XLM.371002.AA-A.stp so i creadted folder named "XLM.371002.AA" so i want to copy .pdf and .stp files in to folder XLM.371002.AA
i tried few methods using .bat at first it worked but i used just 5 folders and 10 files, but when i want to do it over 600-700+ files it doesn't work, powershell opens but does nothing
@echo off
setlocal

pushd "C:\Users\Hakan\Desktop\pdfkarsan"

for /d %%I in (C:\Users\Hakan\Desktop\karsanklasor\*) do (
    for %%F in (*.pdf) do (
        for /f %%A in ('echo %%~nF ^| find /i "%%~nI"') do (
            set /p a="Moving %%F to %%I... "<NUL
            move "%%F" "%%I" >NUL
            echo Done.
        )
    )
)
popd

i found the code from here and just edited it for myself
well it seems started to work after waited 30 minutes apprx. but works so slow like 6 files/h

From what you've submitted, I'd suggest something more like this one line batch file:
@(For /D %%G In ("%UserProfile%\Desktop\karsanklasor\*") Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe "%UserProfile%\Desktop\pdfkarsan" "%%G" "%%~nxG-*.pdf" "%%~nxG-*.stp" /FP /Mov /NDL /NJS /NC /NS) & Pause

It does not replicate your display results, but should give you enough to determine what was being copied, and where to etc.

well thank you at first, it did something but copied the files randomly, half of the folders are empty, located right folders but i checked random folders and more than half were empty

This reliably moves every .pdf and .stp file with a basename beginning with each of your directory names followed by a dash and 0 or more characters, to those directories. If it is not working for you, you have the required permissions to move them, and they are not locked, you have either changed something, (which I will not support), or omitted some important information that I was unable to guess.

i literally just copied your script and created a .bat file, didn't change anything, can those dots "." which appears a lot on my file list cause problem?

sorry it's my fault, i realized in my .pdf files there are underscores too "_"
